# Haar measure on ${\cal P}(\omega)$

Tags: pr.probability, set-theory, measure-theory, haar-measure

First, we note that there is a natural bijection ${\cal P}(\omega) \to \{0,1\}^\omega$ and endow the latter with the product topology (where $\{0,1\}$ carries the discrete topology). So we get a compact space that [can be endowed with a Haar measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar_measure).

Is there a concrete definition of that measure?

More concretely, let $A_0 = \{a \in {\cal P}(\omega): 0 \in a\}$; so what is the Haar measure of $A_0$? (I would expect $1/2$, as "half of the subsets of $\omega$ contain $0$ as a member", but this is just heavy handwaving.)

Comment: What is your group operation?

Comment: If you identify $\{0,1\}^\omega$ with $[0,1]$ via binary expansion, this is just Lebesgue measure. (The set of points with a non-unique expansion has measure $0$ so this is not a problem.) In particular, $A_0 = [0,1/2)$ and therefore does have measure $1/2$.

Comment: "concrete description" is not very clear since the measure is defined on Borel subsets, and giving a concrete description of all Borel subsets themselves is all but easy. However, what's mostly important is the value of the measure on clopen subsets, and it's enough to define it on a basis. A basis is given by the $X_f$ where $f$ ranges over partial functions $\omega\to\{0,1\}$ with finite domain $D_f$, and $X_f$ is the set of functions $g:\omega\to\{0,1\}$ extending $f$. Then the measure of $X_f$ is $2^{-\# D_f}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Arno said, for "Haar measure" you need a group operation.
On $\{0,1\}$, we can define a group using "addition modulo 2".  Normalized Haar measure for that group has each point of measure $1/2$.

Then on $\{0,1\}^\omega$ we use the product group.  In that case, Haar measure is the product measure.  $A_0$ depends only on the first coordinate, and we get measure of $A_0$ in $\{0,1\}^\omega$ is equal to the measure of $\{0\}$ in $\{0,1\}$.  So the measure of $A_0$ is $1/2$.

Of course if you use some different group operation on $\{0,1\}^\omega$, you may get some different Haar measure.

Comment: You are probably asking in the wrong forum, however.